# selecting elements from list according to their labels in the other list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists Lx and Ly, each element from Lx has a corresponding label in Ly. Example:

```
Lx = [[1,2,5], [5,2,7], [7,0,4], [9,2,0], [1,8,5], [3,4,5], [3,2,7], [2,9,7]]
Ly = [A, C, A, B, A, B, C, C]
```

How can easily I get a list/label where elements of a list are the elements from Lx that have the same label in Ly ? That is:

```
[[1,2,5], [7,0,4], [1,8,5]]
[[5,2,7], [3,2,7], [2,9,7]]
[[9,2,0], [3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Lx = [[1,2,5], [5,2,7], [7,0,4], [9,2,0], [1,8,5], [3,4,5], [3,2,7], [2,9,7]]
Ly = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
d = {}
for x,y in zip(Lx,Ly):
    d.setdefault(y, []).append(x)
```

`d` is now:

```
{'A': [[1, 2, 5], [7, 0, 4], [1, 8, 5]],
 'B': [[9, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5]],
 'C': [[5, 2, 7], [3, 2, 7], [2, 9, 7]]}
```

Comment: @shn If you do ``from collections import OrderedDict`` and ``d = OrderedDict()`` , the order of the lists in ``d.values()`` reflects the order of the elements in Ly

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you pretty close:

```
from collections import defaultdict

Lx = [[1,2,5], [5,2,7], [7,0,4], [9,2,0], [1,8,5], [3,4,5], [3,2,7], [2,9,7]]
Ly = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in zip(Lx, Ly):
  d[y].append(x)
d = dict(d)

print(d)
```

This produces

```
{'A': [[1, 2, 5], [7, 0, 4], [1, 8, 5]], 'C': [[5, 2, 7], [3, 2, 7], [2, 9, 7]], 'B': [[9, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5]]}
```